# how to read CSV in ruby 1.8.7?

Tags: ruby, csv, ruby-1.8.7

I just want to read a csv file and discard the header row.

When I do `csv = CSV.read('file_name.csv','r')` I get

> .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/csv.rb:98:in `read': can't
>   convert String into Integer (TypeError)

When I do

```
csv = CSV.open('file_name.csv','r')
csv.shift
```

I get

> .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/csv.rb:639:in `get_row':
>   CSV::IllegalFormatError (CSV::IllegalFormatError)
>   from .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/csv.rb:567:in `shift'

What is an example of successfully reading csv files and manipulating data in ruby 1.8.7?

---

**edit:**

first few lines of file_name.csv

```
Request, Target
http://www.asdf.com/,http://www.asdf.com/
http://www.asdf.com/_blank,http://www.asdf.com/
"http://www.asdf.com/,",http://www.asdf.com/
```

Comment: Please post the content of file_name.csv, or at least the first lines.

Comment: If you're still using Ruby 1.8.7 you're in dire need of updating, but you might be able to muddle along using the [CSV library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) if you read the documentation carefully. Keep in mind this is **unsupported software** so you're basically on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
csv = CSV.read('file_name.csv')
```

`"r"` is not a correct parameter for [`CSV.read`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html)

Answer (score 0):

The file line endings was the issue.
I changed all of them to unix's LF.